# Convergence of the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to find out whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$ convergent and I know the alternating series test. However, I don't know whether the absolute term converges to 0 or not. I already show that it is not absolutely convergent. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may observe that, as $n \to \infty$, by the use of the [Stirling formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation),
$$
\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}=\frac{2^n\cdot n!}{\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n n!}}=\frac{2^{2n} (n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}\sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\frac1{\sqrt{n}}
$$ and the initial series is **not absolutely convergent**.

In fact, as $n \to \infty$, by using [the asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation#Derivation),
$$
n! = \sqrt{2 \pi}n^{n+1/2} e^{-n} \left( 1 + O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)
$$ we get

> $$
> (-1)^n\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+ O \left( \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \right) 
> $$

**the initial series is convergent** being the sum of two convergent series.

One may prove that

> $$
> \sum_{n\geq1}(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2\log \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)-1.
> $$

Comment: I see, however, is there any more elementary way to solve this?

Comment: Maybe it's interesting to note that holds $$\frac{\sinh^{-1}\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^{n}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}x^{2n+1}$$ for $-1\leq x\leq1$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have some links for this equality?